# PIL putpixels function

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL to make the colors of an image just round off to the closest color. However, when doing so I run into many errors using the function `putpixel`. I have tried converting the RGB values to `int` in case they were `float`. I tried just using the `int` form of the RGB but nothing seems to be working so far.

Below is my attempt:

```py
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("milford_sound_new_zealand_bay_reflection_mountains_104080_1920x1080.jpg");

out = Image.new('I', im.size, 0xffffff);

col_amt = 10;
cold = []

def nearest(arr, val):
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    idx = (np.abs(arr - val)).argmin()
    return arr[idx]

def rgbint(r,g,b):
    rgb = r;
    rgb = (rgb << 8) + g
    rgb = (rgb << 8) + b
    return rgb

def intrgb(rgb):
    return(rgb // 256 // 256 % 256, rgb // 256 % 256, rgb % 256)


for i in range(col_amt):
    rgb = ((256*256*256)-1)/(col_amt-1) * i;
    #print(rgb);
    cold.append(rgb)

cold = np.array(cold)

width, height = im.size
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        r,g,b = im.getpixel((x,y))
        d = rgbint(r,g,b)
        cd = nearest(cold, d)
        rgb = intrgb(cd)
        #if b < g and b < r or r==g==b:
        #print(rgb)
        out.putpixel((x,y),(int(rgb[0]), int(rgb[1]), int(rgb[2])))

out.save('bar.png')
```

Comment: you have to use `'RGB'` instead of `'I'` in `Image.new()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put `R,G,B` so you have to use `'RGB'` instead of `'I'` in

```
out = Image.new('RGB', im.size, 0xffffff)
```

For `I` you would have to put `int(cd)`

```
out.putpixel((x, y), int(cd))
```

because it expects 32-bit value instead of 3x8-bit value

Doc: [Modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes)